# How to save a Python dtype('object') in an HDF5 file?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5

I am trying to load data from .mat files into python, so that I can save it in an HDF5 file.

The problem is `scipy.io.loadmat` returns a dictionary containing arrays of dtype=[('counts', '|O4')])

Whenever I try to create a dataset with one of the arrays returned, I get the following error:

```
>> mat = scipy.io.loadmat('state-10.mat')
>> h = h5py.File('test.hdf5','w')
>> h.create_dataset('set', data=mat['ProteinComplex'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py", line 69, in create_dataset
    dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(self, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 88, in make_new_dset
    tid = h5t.py_create(dtype, logical=1)
  File "h5t.pyx", line 1332, in h5py.h5t.py_create (h5py/h5t.c:11600)
  File "h5t.pyx", line 1373, in h5py.h5t.py_create (h5py/h5t.c:11209)
  File "h5t.pyx", line 1311, in h5py.h5t._c_compound (h5py/h5t.c:10695)
  File "h5t.pyx", line 1332, in h5py.h5t.py_create (h5py/h5t.c:11600)
  File "h5t.pyx", line 1402, in h5py.h5t.py_create (h5py/h5t.c:11465)
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('object') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

Is there any workaround from this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out the type of `mat['ProteinComplex']` is a scipy multidimensional array (ndarray). It is possible to convert these to lists with the `ndarray.tolist()` method. If we change the nd array into a list it will work when creating the dataset with H5Py

```
>> mat = scipy.io.loadmat('state-10.mat')
>> h = h5py.File('test.hdf5','w')
>> protein_complex = mat['ProteinComplex'].tolist()
>> h.create_dataset('ProteinComplex', data=protein_complex)
```